# How to split the single linearlayout into two linear layout

Tags: android, image, layout, bitmap, signature

I have downloaded [a project](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html) regarding signing a signature on the linear layout.

**What I am trying to do?**

In my project i am going to split the linear layout into two linear layouts,in that first layout i can put the signature on the images and i need to save in gallery , in another layout I will write something on the images and save into gallery as the single layout in to the gallery,

But in the project I can save only first layout itself, but I need to write on second layout and I need to save in gallery. please any one help me out.

Comment: what are you exactly asking??

Answer (score 1):

You can divide into two equal `LinearLayout` like this..

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

{Put all those you want to come in 1st layout here}

  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

{Put all those you want to come in 2nd layout here}

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But this code I already used it is not working for my project,I can able to put sign in one layout itself I had executed my layout through in java code it self please kindly look at my project link and give me some other useful answers please.

Comment: I can split the layout when I used this code, But I can put signature in second layout only how can i write something in first layout also I want to write something in both layouts.

Comment: See my edited answer..Put your signature inside the first Layout..ie between opening and closing of `LinearLayout`

Comment: yes, if I comment the second layout I can write in first layout.

Comment: Now I can write in both layouts I can save it in gallery as same image,but I am getting one issue,if I start to draw in the first layout I can write only in first layout itself,and If I start to draw from second layout I can draw in second layout itself,but I can not draw a line in both layouts at the same time.

Comment: i dint get you @Manoj ..You want to draw line in both layouts???How are you drawing line in the layouts??

Comment: When I start to touch from first layout I can write only in first layout if I move my finger from first to second it couldn't responding in second layout(because Initially I started with first layout). If I need to write in second layout I have to start only in second layout(if I started in second layout I can write text only in second layout.if I move my finger to first it wouldn't responding in first layout because initially I have started in second layout). I do not like to click each time for writing a text over the both layout. I need to touch one time for writing text in both layout.

Comment: Sorry @Manoj, I think its not possible...You'll have to click each time on both layouts whenever you wnat to type in any of the layouts..

Comment: k fine Mr.Lal if you find output for this task kindly comment on my account.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:weightsum="2"
 android:orientation=""// horizontal or veritical
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```